# Links don't work using MVC 4 on an iPhone

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using jQuery Accordion. It works perfectly on all devices except on the iPad and iPhone. On these devices not of my links work.Even if I have a simple link to another page nothing happens. I've been trying to track this issue down for a few months. Any suggestions?

It work fine on an android device.

Comment: Your links not working on iPhone has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: I realize that. I tested out my site using Electric Plum emulator for the iPad and iPhone and it works.My problem is when I actuality use the iPhone or iPad the links don't work.

Comment: *I realize that.* - then why is your question tagged with MVC twice and why does it mention MVC in the title? You need to debug the issue sufficiently that you can post some code here that will reproduce the problem.

Comment: My web app was designed using MVC 4 and JQuery Mobile. That's why I mentioned MVC 4 twice. There is no point in putting up any code since none of my links work using the iPad or iPhone. The site works if I use the Electric Plum emulator .

Comment: Can you show the link code ?

Comment: <a href="/Home/Display?row=64">
                    <img src="../../Images/Pina Colada.jpg">
                </a>

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your styles. Still impossible to debug without seeing the relevant code. Again, a reproducible example is required.

Comment: Here's a link to my site whatscookingtreasures.com.

Comment: <footer>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="/Home/Comments">Contact Us</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/Home/About">About</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="/Home/Rss">RSS Feeds</a>
                </td>
                
                            </tr>
        </div>
    </footer>